# How can I archive file with name coming from the Max lastwritetime and Min lastwritetime

Tags: powershell

I am trying to archive files where LastWriteTime is before yesterday and rename the archive zip file with max last write time and min last write time but with no success.

How can I reference the maximum and minimum values as parameters(such as $1,$2) in the naming part?

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path "E:\Archive\Tracking" | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Measure-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Minimum -Maximum | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "E:\Archive\Tracking_Zip\$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).zip" -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force
```

For example, the Max LastWriteTime is 2021-01-28 and the Min LastWriteTime is 2021-01-01, so the archive zip file name should be `20210101_20210128.zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the best to step away from trying to put everything in a oneliner.
There is no advantage in doing so as `Measure-Object` needs to stall the pipeline anyways to determine the "*Max LastWriteTime and the Min LastWriteTime*".

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path "E:\Archive\Tracking" | Where{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) }
$Measure = $Files | Measure-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Minimum -Maximum
$FilePath = 'E:\Archive\Tracking_Zip\{0:yyyyMMdd}_{1:yyyyMMdd}.zip' -f $Measure.Minimum, $Measure.Maximum
$Files | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $FilePath -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force
```